# jquery mobile form not submitting

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I have just started to use the jquery mobile library and have hit a snag. In my old login system, I used a form where the action referenced a class and handled the login and sessions. With html5 layout, for some reason, the form is always showing as incorrect. Can someone show me where I have gone wrong with this. At the moment I am using ajax to handle the login but would prefer to use the form method. Thanks

```
<div data-role="content">
     <div data-role="fieldcontain">
     <form method="post" id="login" action="<?php echo KT_escapeAttribute(KT_getFullUri()); ?>" class="webform">
        <label for="kt_login_user">Email *</label>
        <input type="text" name="kt_login_user" id="kt_login_user" value="<?php echo KT_escapeAttribute($row_rscustom['kt_login_user']); ?>" size="66" placeholder="janedoe@example.com" />
        <?php echo $tNGs->displayFieldHint("kt_login_user");?>
        <?php echo $tNGs->displayFieldError("custom", "kt_login_user"); ?>
     </div>

     <div data-role="fieldcontain">
      <label for="kt_login_password">Password *</label>
        <label for="kt_login_rememberme"></label>
        <input type="password" name="kt_login_password" id="kt_login_password" value="" size="46" placeholder="******" />
        <div id="login_message"></div>
            <?php echo $tNGs->displayFieldHint("kt_login_password");?>
            <?php echo $tNGs->displayFieldError("custom", "kt_login_password"); ?>
            <?php echo $tNGs->displayFieldError("custom", "kt_login_rememberme"); ?>

        </div>
        <input name="kt_login1" id="kt_login1" type="submit" value="Login" data-inline="true" />
        </form>
        <?php  echo $tNGs->getErrorMsg() ;?>
        <?php   echo $tNGs->getLoginMsg(); ?>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are hoping to use form for validation etc. you can get the same using jquerys validation API.

What are the other compelling reasons ti use form??

Hope this helps.

Comment: zzzz Because the login and session system is already written in php and I was reluctant to write a new one. Time constraints. Thanks